# Incentive for Extra Reputation

Tags: feature-request, weekly-topic-challenge, reputation

I believe that we should try get our programmer friends at StackExchange HQ to program Mi.Yodeya into giving users extra reputation for asking and answering questions that fall into the *Weekly Topic Challenge* categories. Anything that falls into the certain weekly (or monthly?) tag categories (To Be Determined based on the week) should be fair game for this promotion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they would do that just for Mi Yodeya. (And we sort of dropped topic challenges a while ago, and yes, i see the post date.)

However, now that [SE is more endorsing weekly topic challenges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240634/how-do-weekly-topic-challenges-work), this might be a good idea to take to MSE.